# display none when no images in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm using jquery get the src of images to display:none when src="". It looks like that,

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="images_path/or nothing" class="Images"/>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

class content float left to fit with images width in parent div. Now I want detect image source when it empty I changed class content.width to fit with parent div by its selft.
My jquery code like that

```
var CustomizeImage = $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").attr("src");
alert(CustomizeImage);
if(CustomizeImage == ""){
    alert("ko co gi");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").css("display","none");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".news").css("width","320px");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Content").css("width","320px");
}
```

But class content does not get new width even src=empty, someone help me to fix this truoble, thank alot of read my note!!!

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try lowercasing “.Content” (change to “.content”) in the script. Cause in HTML you have just class="content".

Answer (score 0):

Since class names are case-sensitive in CSS, `.Content` doesn't match `class="content"`

Either change the class to `class="Content"` in the HTML (which seems to be your naming convention anyway), or the selector to `.content`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Tobias and Birman alot, I've just check out my class name in css file is Content. and I mean I have s list of parent div. But my code just alert the first one when I code like that:

```
var CustomizeImage = $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").attr("src");
alert(CustomizeImage);
if(CustomizeImage == ""){
    alert("ko co gi");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").css("display","none");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".news").css("width","320px");
    $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Content").css("width","320px");
} else {
    if(CustomizeImage.indexOf('src=""') > 0){
        alert("co nhung rong");
        $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").css("display","none");
        $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".news").css("width","320px");
        $(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Content").css("width","320px");
    }
}
```

and my html code look like this:

```
<div class="CategoryNews-left">
    <div class="Images">
        <img src="images/Anhto_listtin_trai.gif" alt="anh tin" />
</div>
<div class="news">
    <h3>blahblahblahblahblah</h3>
    <p>blahblah- blahblahblah</p>
</div>
<div class="Content">blahblahblahblahblahblah</div>
<div class="relateNews">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah</a> <font>VnExpress</font></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think you should be doing this:  
if(CustomizeImage.indexOf('src=""') > 0)  
It will never actually contain the string "src=.." so just try removing this if statement all together

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but your first selection is wrong.

```
$(".CategoryNews-left").find(".Images").attr("src");
```

Finds the **div** "images", and looks for its `src`. The div has no src.
You should try

```
$(".CategoryNews-left .Images img").attr("src");
```

Also, keep in mind `attr("src")` will only return the src of the first img, even if you have many.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Kobi and the other alot! Now I know if I want to have their attributes I must get the loop throught all element. And now it run. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: No problem, welcome. Feel free to mark any of the answers as your solution.